# Can a Herglotz-Nevanlinna function attain real values?

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $\mathbb{H}^+=\{z \in \mathbb{C}\mid \Im(z)>0\}$. We say that an analytic $F\colon \mathbb{H}^+\to\overline{\mathbb{H}^+}$ is a *Herglotz-Nevanlinna*'s function.

**Question** Can it be that $F(z)\in \mathbb{R}$ for some $z \in \mathbb{H}^+$?

I guess that the answer is no, because if this happened then we could find a small loop $\gamma$ around $z$ such that $F\circ \gamma$ slips outside $\overline{\mathbb{H}^+}$, but I'm not sure this is true and how to formalize this little argument.

Thank you.

Comment: Of course in both this question and the answer by Davide Giraudo it is assumed that $F$ is not constant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $F$ is constant it's clear, otherwise, since $\mathbb H^+$ is connected, by the open mapping theorem, $F(\mathbb H^+)$ is open in $\mathbb C$. If $F(z)\in\Bbb R$ for some $z\in\mathbb H^+$, then we can find $r$ such that if $|y-F(z)|<2r$ then $y=F(y')$ for some $y'\in\mathbb H^+$. If we consider $F(z)-ri$, we get a contradiction.

Comment: Aw, thank you! This was a good occasion to review the open mapping theorem (which evidently I had forgotten! :-) ).

Comment: You are welcome. In which context do we use such maps?

Comment: Measure theory and spectral analysis. Specifically I am reading this lecture by Terence Tao: http://terrytao.wordpress.com/2011/12/20/the-spectral-theorem-and-its-converses-for-unbounded-symmetric-operators/ . Have a look at Theorem 4.